Understand about IGBT and MOSFET
I'm studying about IGBT and MOSFET devices but information on the internet is difficult for me to understand, especially for their important properties.
Please help me to summarise this content or could you recommend some good documents to study?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulated-gate_bipolar_transistor, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET

You can read application notes on IGBT and MOSFETS from different semiconductor companies such as ST, Infineon and NXP. They have application notes and design guidelines documents which you can use in your designs. The other alternative is to read books which contain sufficient amount of information on IGBT and MOSFET. Rarely books contain so much practical information.

What have you researched so far, and what issues are you having with the sources? Simply asking for a summary, smells like a homework assignment -- for which you must show some some effort at attempting a solution.

The most important fundamental difference is apparent for high voltage devices.
With MOSFETs, the resistance tends to rise as the voltage rating of the device rises. Once you get above roughly 500 V, the voltage drop when on through this high resistance starts to become excessive.
That's where the IGBT takes over, at higher voltages. With its bipolar-like construction, the voltage drop when on tends to a constant saturation level, regardless of voltage rating.
At low voltages, the low resistance of the MOSFET tends to win over the constant voltage drop of the IGBT.
That's the main difference. They have a lot of similarities. High resistance but very capacitive input, big Miller capacitance from output to control terminal, and a steady improvement in figures of merit as development goes on.
As improvement takes place in both parts from time to time, the crossover voltage for 'voltage drop when on' will change. As Hearth points out in comments, SiC has produced such an improvement in RDSon versus VDS for MOSFETs that they are capable of displacing the present generation of IGBTs at all voltages, at a price.

Small addendum: Silicon carbide MOSFETs are beginning to displace IGBTs, because you can get lower-resistance SiC MOSFETs at higher voltages than traditional silicon ones. They're more expensive than comparable silicon IGBTs, but can improve efficiency.

@Hearth that's the 'steady improvement' I hinted at. However, maybe a change of material is not 'steady' but 'disruptive'.
